# Admin Hello World Question

Tags: admin

`VMRReports/AdminHelloWorld/etc/config.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <module>
        <VMRReports_AdminHelloWorld>  <!-- Explain this line so like: Namespace_Modulename_IDunno -->
            <version>1.0</version>
        </VMRReports_AdminHelloWorld>
    </module>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <helloworld before="Mage_Adminhtml">VMRReports_AdminHelloWorld</helloworld>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

HelloWorldController.php:

```
<?php 

class VMRReports_AdminHelloWorld_HelloWorldController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action {        
    protected $_publicActions = array('index');
    public function IndexAction() {
        echo 'Hello Index! HelloWorld';
//  $this->loadLayout();
//  $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

================================

This shows up in /magento/index.php/admin/HelloWorld/index/

How do I get it to show up in

/magento/index.php/admin/helloworld/index/ ???

And by this I meant, is it possible to use the camel case I am using while forcing the URL to remain all lowercase?

Comment: I think the answer below is the right answer, because I saw an other question you posted as a follow-up. Please accept the answer so you don't leave loose end. It breaks the website statistics and while in beta it could really use good figures.

Answer (score 2):

Just name your controller
`VMRReports_AdminHelloWorld_HelloworldController` instead of
`VMRReports_AdminHelloWorld_HelloWorldController`

Also the file name should be `HelloworldController.php:` (lowercase 'w').

**EDIT**
Although it should work the way you do it just by changing what I suggested, the best practice is to put your admin controllers in a folder called `Adminhtml` to separate them from the front controllers.
So the file should actually be `app/code/local/VMRReports/AdminHelloWorld/controllers/Adminhtml/HelloworldController.php`
The class name should be `VMRReports_AdminHelloWorld_Adminhtml_HelloworldController`
and the config routing should be:

```
<helloworld before="Mage_Adminhtml">VMRReports_AdminHelloWorld_Adminhtml</helloworld>
```